# How to make multithreaded swing gui application start/stop thread with 2 buttons

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a separate class implementing runnable, but whenever I start the thread, I cannot press the stop button on the GUI. I'm not sure whether I am doing things correctly as I have never done multithreading before in Java project of this scale. I'm already far into the project, and I hadn't tested the stop thread function until now.

I looked into implementing things like this, but I wasn't sure how: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

These are the bits of code to start and stop the thread

```
Runnable r;
Thread t1;
String token,proxies,sID,msgC;
```

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Start Thread");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                token=txtEnterBotToken.getText();
                proxies=textArea.getText();
                sID=txtEnterServerId.getText();
                msgC=textField_1.getText();
                r=null;
                t1=new Thread(r);
                r = new BotFunc(token,proxies,sID,msgC);
                if(!t1.isAlive())t1.start();
                }
            });
```

```
JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Stop Thread");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                t1.interrupt();
                t1=new Thread(r);
            }
        });
```

This is what my class which is being initialized in the other thread looks like

```
public class BotFunc implements Runnable {
    private String token1,proxies1,sID1,msgC1;
    
    public BotFunc(String token,String proxies,String sID,String msgC) {
           token1=token;proxies1=proxies;sID1=sID;msgC1=msgC;
           run();
       }
    
    public void run()
    {
        {
            {
                System.out.println("t1 running");
                //there were about 1000 lines here that I deleted in which I start 2 other threads
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can also see where I write "//there were about 1000 lines here that I deleted in which I start 2 other threads." The classes which are initialized are mostly similar to the BotFunc class and I was wondering how I could interrupt these threads as well.

Comment: `I cannot press the stop button on the GUI.` Is the GUI still running at all?  Usually this means you have blocked the main GUI thread.  Do any of the method calls above block for any amount of time?

Comment: I'm not sure. The GUI isn't completely frozen, but I can't press any of the buttons. I can still move it around unlike when C++ applications I used to work on would freeze completely.

Comment: Moving the main window around is handled by the OS, I don't think Java is involved.  Just a different way of handling the GUI and events, Java lets the OS handle some window functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is calling `run()` from the constructor of `BotFunc`:

```
public BotFunc(String token,String proxies,String sID,String msgC) {
       token1=token;proxies1=proxies;sID1=sID;msgC1=msgC;
       run();  // <---- DON'T DO THIS!!
   }
```

Calling `run()` like this will execute the code body on the main GUI thread, causing the GUI to block.  Don't do this.

Just to explain a bit more, `Thread.start()` calls `run()` for you, there's no need for you to do it.

```
/* Fake Thread implementation */
public class Thread {
   public void start() {
     /* starts a new thread, then... */
     run(); // just calls run()
   }
}
```

Calling `run()` from the ctor causes the GUI thread to run the body of your `Runnable`, because it's the GUI thread that calls the ctor, and the body of the ctor is just executing on the GUI thread as a result.

Comment: What could I do alternatively?

Comment: Just don't call `run()`.  Why would you?  The code gets executed when you call `Thread.start()`, there's no need to run this in the ctor.